# What does the phrase "get someone to move" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Here is the sentence:

> This year saw apps that got us to move, and games we were moved by.

I am not sure about the meaning of the words "got us to move" here.

Answer (score 1):

Think of *Pokémon Go*, or *Zombies, Run!* - or *Dance Dance Revolution* (though one typically doesn't use the word *app* for console games): applications that literally cause us to move (as opposed to being usable while one is sitting down, or lying in the bed, like most applications).

This is in contrast to "games we were moved by", where "moved" is used metaphorically, for "games we were emotionally impacted by".